# Submit in app purchase for review for first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I am working on in app purchase.
After submitting all the details in app purchase gives me status "Ready to Submit".

But the "Submit For Review" button is disabled in my app's in app purchase.
This is giving me this warning

"Your first In-App Purchase must be submitted with a new app version. Select it from the app’s In-App Purchases section and click Submit."

I can't understand what to do. If anybody knows solution please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your IAP is all setup and ready to be submitted with the next update of your application. Select the IAP when submitting the next update for your application, it will be available to select on the same page where you edit your apps App Store description, screenshots, keywords, etc...

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If your application is in Waiting for review state then you can submit your IAP by rejecting current version & uploading new version.

Otherwise your IAP will be available once you upload a new version on iTunes Store.

"Your first In-App Purchase must be submitted with a new app version. Select it from the app’s In-App Purchases section and click Submit."

The meaning of above line is when you submit your app for review you need to select the IAPs from the application detail page. You will see In App Purchase section on Application detail page (Page on which description,Keywords,etc displaying). You need to select required IAP from that page & then need to submit your application again.

Let me know if you need anymore clarification for this.

Comment: Do I need to upload my app also when I am submitting In app purchase for review for the first time.

Comment: Yes, Actually when you upload first version of the application at that time you need to select required In App purchase. From next version you don't need to take care of this. Let me know if you still need anymore clarification

Comment: How Do I test my in app is successful or not

Comment: Once you upload your new app with IN App purchase then status of IN App Purchase also changed to Waiting For Review. That way you will come to know that your IAP was submitted successfully.

Comment: One last question please I am working on content based where I want to release additional contents of my app after user purchase So How do i can do this.

Comment: Content means? Digital content OR Physical Goods?

Comment: It is just some more functionality which is hidden from user and when user can purchase then additional functionality will be available to user.

Comment: You need to do code for all those functionality & need to provide all access to it once user complete IN APP purchase process. Got it?

Comment: That means every time when user login Do I need to check that user have completed IAP process or not?

Comment: Yes, It depend on your implementation. If you would like to check at login then you can check at that time.

Comment: So does this mean that I must submit a fully completed app and hope that it doesn't make the App Store before I have a change to debug and test my IAP? Seems strange that I can't test my IAP until it's in waiting for review state.

Comment: No, You don't have to submit app to Apple for review. You just need to register the application so application status will be prepare for submission state only.

Comment: When i was uploading build first time, option to select in app purchase was available below build and the status for in app purchase was "Ready to submit". But after the rejection when i am uploading same build version with different build number, i am not having option to select in app purchase for that build number. Is it because my in app purchase status is changed to "waiting for review".

Comment: how to demo app video create for my iPhone objective c  application

Comment: @AkhileshSharma have you find any solution for this

Comment: @AJSanjay Did you find any solution for this after AkhileshSharma disappeared into the ether?

Comment: Just to follow up on AkhileshSharma's message, the reason the subscription isn't appearing is because you need to submit a new *version* not a new build number. Eg, if your app was previously 3.0.0 you submit 3.0.1. It's still stupid, and completely unintuitive - also wastes time if your IAP gets rejected.

Comment: @JCraine Nope We made different payment mechanism

Comment: how can I test the In App purchase . every time I test it say invalid product ids

Answer (score 47):

In addition to what was said by Nilesh -

You must create your IAP from under the Features->In App Purchase. Then you must add a screenshot, so that the IAP says Ready to Submit.

*Then* from the Prepare for Submission page, the section titled InApp purchases shows up (otherwise it is hidden) and you can select your inapp purchase you just created.

Comment: Where is the "iOS App binary editable" page? I have looked everywhere and I couldn't find the page where I can select my in-app purchase for review.

Comment: It is the Prepare for Submission page

Comment: @TimCooley Where is the Prepare for Submission page?

Answer (score 13):

Thanks very much for @David Skelly's answer.

To do IAP review is very important.

---

**The OK one:**

- master page

[image: one]

- detail page

[image: two]

---

**The not OK one:**

- master page

[image: aaa]

- detail page

[image: bbb]