# Submit button is missing for in app purchase for review for first time

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

I presume Apple has changed the layout of iTunes Connect and the location where you add in-app purchases, so this is the screen where I add in-app purchase, however it tells me to *Select it from the app’s In-App Purchases section and click Submit*. 
[image]

Which again I presume is the following area, which I can't see any where to submit in-app purchase: [image]

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30481475/submit-in-app-purchase-for-review-for-first-time) and it's answer, there should be an in-app purchase part but it is missing.

P.S. This is going to be the first submission for the app.

Comment: Have you already had a version approved with in-app purchaes? If not then the in-app purchases will be submitted when you submit your app for approval

Comment: @Paulw11 no i don't have a version approved. What confuses me is, i have submit the app for review, then status changed to 'in review' however in-app purchase status is still 'ready to submit' and when i open the in-app purchase page it tells me to submit it from app's in-app purchases.

Comment: Some trouble. My app is already "on Sale" but INAPP not available yet and see INAPP status is - "ready to submit", but in INAPP detail show disabled "Submit for review" button.
Do you solve this?

Comment: @DmitriyPushkarev please see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is going to be the case for everyone, however in my case what happened is as follows:

- I've submitted only the app itself not the in-app purchase, since there were no option to submit it.
- Then my app got rejected by Apple, saying they weren't able to find the in-app purchase.
- After being rejected, ***In-App Purchase*** section appeared between ***Build*** and ***General App Information***.
- Then I've selected my in-app purchase in that section and submit the **app** again, not the in-app.
- After submitting the app, in-app purchase is submitted automatically.

As I said, this might not be the case for everyone, maybe some people see that In-App Purchase section before being rejected. Only thing that's for sure is you have to select in-app purchase from a list before submitting the app.

Comment: This helped me in 2023!

Answer (score 8):

The In-App purchase section won't appear unless you have at least one In-App Purchase with a status of "Ready to Submit" under the Features tab in the In-App Purchases section.

Since your's shows as "Ready to Submit", simply go back to your app's page, click the "Prepare for Submission" tab on the left side of the screen, and then scroll down until you find the In-App Purchases section.  It is right below General App Information.

I had several listed there, but they were each missing a photo so their status was Missing Meta Data instead of Ready to Submit.

Comment: just to add to this answer: My app wasn't showing the IAP till about 30 minutes (presume some weird propagation issue). I then pulled my app from the review queue so it became Developer Rejected. It then allowed me to add the IAP to it and resubmit.