# iOS In-app purchase nightmare

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, cordova-plugins

We are developing an App with Ionic and [cordova-plugin-inapppurchase](https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase). We've been struggling more than a week as we get the following error when we try to restore a purchase:

> RMStore: unknown product id com.company.appname.myID
>
> {"errorMessage":"Unknown product identifier","errorCode":100}

```
productId = 'com.company.appname.myID';
```

Comment: So far, this helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30481475/submit-in-app-purchase-for-review-for-first-time

Comment: don't you hate when such a great question attracts 0 response? I got the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

This post is old, but I was able to fix this problem for myself tonight.  Using Ionic v1 with the cordova-plugin-inapppurchase, my solution was to change `com.company.appname.myID` to just `myID` (the product id of the in app purchase).

I also had a few other problems causing the same exact error message.  The main one was needing to `inAppPurchase.getProducts(productIds)` before attempting `inAppPurchase.buy(productId)`.  Also, make sure you're testing on a real device, with a test account created on iTunes connect, and logged out of any other apple ids on your device (I signed out through the iTunes Store app).

Good luck future readers!

Comment: I love it when people answer old questions and especially when they give me multiple solutions. Thanks Matt. I'm sorry the OP isnt here to mark this as correct

Comment: I'm glad I could help Ian! It's no problem - helping others is the whole point. Good luck with your app.

Comment: @MattGoodrich Thank you! I was struggling with this as well and didn't realize the getProducts call was needed first!