# App Rejected - In App Purchase Auto-Renewable Subscription - Developer action needed

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

my In-App Purchase item (**Auto-Renewable** subscription item) keep beeing rejected from iOS App Store Review team but I cannot understand what it's wrong with it.

This is my In-App Purchase page. As you can see there is "**Developer action needed**":
[image: In-App Purchase item list]

This is the detail inside the item:

[image: detail item]
As you can see, there are 2 red dots next to the localization messages.
I tried to change them several times (the last change I did was reversing title with the description), with no success.

I read this guide -> https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev06f89ce98 and I followed all the steps and tried to be as much similar as I could with my In-App Purchase product.

Can you help me?

Comment: Just like app, you need to submit the required IAP. When you submits your IAP status will be changed to "Submitted". After that you need to submit your app. Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30481475/submit-in-app-purchase-for-review-for-first-time

Comment: Hi @dahiya_boy thanks for your reply. Yes, I know this... The problem is that Apple guys say there is a "developer action needed" but I don't know where. Do you see any misconfiguration in those localizations strings?

Comment: Hey @GiuseppeMatrella,  Were you able to figure out what was the reason for the rejected localizations? I am experiencing the same issue and I am not able to find any useful information, so I would really appreciate your help